# At how many elements will $in be a slow operation?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql, aggregation-framework, mongodb-indexes

In my app, users can block other users. There will be queries where I will need to find

```
$in: [use_id_x, array_that_contains_all_blocked_user_ids]
```

At what length of `array_that_contains_all_blocked_user_ids` will this operation become slow.

If it is expected that a user can block up to block 100,000 users, how can I design my schema such that this operation will scale?

Comment: If its an array that must no exceeds 16mb of doc size if it exceeds working set leads to drop query performance . alternative to this extended reference pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't find any things in [official doc of `$in`(aggregation)](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/#definition).

However, in [official doc of `$in`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/in/), it stated that:

> It is recommended that you limit the number of parameters passed to the
> $in
> operator to tens of values. Using hundreds of parameters or more can negatively impact query performance.

My interpretation is that the official recommendation is below 100. But at the end, I think it depends on what is "slow" to you, and that highly depends on your actual scenario like system specs, and performance requirements...